# How to prevent the sending of e-mails and contact numbers through a messaging system

Tags: php, filtering, chat, messaging

I am implementing a messaging system using PHP, where each one of my  users can chat with each other. I however need to prevent them from communicating outside the platform.

How can I filter the sending of e-mails and phone numbers ? Airbnb for example is able to do this.

Thank you very much

Answer (score -1):

The simplest way is to filter the messages with `filter_var` or

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.php

Or you can use regular expression.